# Android: adapter wont let me use xml and id's that i created

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an adapter for a listview that wont allow me to use my own xml files, drawables or Id's. It only lets me use things that are in the adk like

```
android.R.id.text1
```

but i want to be able to use this

```
R.id.myOWNtext
```

This is the adapter

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
        android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1,
        new String[]{
                getString(R.string.title_section1),
                getString(R.string.title_section2),
                getString(R.string.title_section3),
                getString(R.string.title_section4),
                getString(R.string.title_section5),
        }));
```

This is fine with me BUT when i try to edit this file android.R.layout.activity_list_item, or any other one NOTHING happens. I even erased everything inside the activity_list_item file and still it acted as if there was no changes made.

When i use my own stuff in the adapter i get the error below:

```
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:353)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1636)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:695)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1609)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1466)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7375)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7375)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7375)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7375)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7375)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7375)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7375)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1158)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
04-10 17:08:24.670: E/AndroidRuntime(30940):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are instancing the adapter implies that:

- it will use android.R.layout.activity_list_item as the layout for each item
- it will use a TextView with id android.R.id.text1 as the TextView to place the texts in

It makes sense you are changing the layout and nothing happens, because the layout you are passing (android.R.layout.activity_list_item) exists in the SDK. You cannot change it, you need to create a new layout.

When you try with a new layout and you get that NullPointerException, it may be because the layout does not have a TextView with the same id you are passing in the constructor of the adapter.

So, I you need a custom layout for each item you need to:

- declare your layout, which should include one TextView
- in the constructor of the adapter, pass the id of your layout and the id of the textview in your layout

Comment: The adapter is not a custom adapter

Comment: Even if it is not a custom adapter (in the sense that you a directly using an ArrayAdapter instead of BaseAdapter), the id of the textview that you pass in the constructor must correlate the id of a textview that needs to exist in the layout that you pass to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

android.R.layout.activity_list_item is a layout belonging to the Android system, and not one that you are allowed to change. You need to create (and use in your call to the ArrayAdapter constructor) your own layout file if you want something to change.

Comment: This is what i am saying above. It wona allow me to use my own

Comment: In the code snippet in your question, you are using "android.R.layout.activity_list_item". You need to reference your own resource instead. If you are already doing that, then please update the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Usually  this happens when your xml file is not properly  saved or there may be an issue some where in xml which won't allow you to get IDz  from R.java file.